# Bash zenity with command line

Tags: bash, zenity

I want to give a user option to choose installation with GUI or commandline. I want to put it all into single script but I cannot figure out if there is a option in zenity to silent all the other commanfline output when zenity is in use. Maybe there is some other way to achive what I want? I was thinking about two separate scripts - one with zennity and the other with commandline but if anything will change I will have to update both scripts...

Comment: What other command-line output?

Comment: At the moment I have command-line prompts asking user for specific data. I want to extend the ability of the script to allow user to choose if he wants to go with command line prompts or zenity UI.

Comment: So where is the problem?